# send html code when using onclick()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string

I'm getting syntax error when using this code:

```
$('#column1').append('<span class="link_style"><a href="#" onClick="show_text(' +  new_cities[i][j].content + ')"></a></span>');
```

When javascript executes I'm getting this code generated:

```
<a href="#" onclick="show_text(<p>description</p>)">Moscow</a>
```

and this would be the function which is producing error:

```
function show_text(text)
    {
        alert(text);
    }
```

`new_cities[i][j].content` has this value `"<p>description</p>"` so basically my data is represented as string so there is definitely some problem in the quotes....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to change this:

```
"show_text(' +  new_cities[i][j].content + ')"
```

into this :

```
"show_text(\'' +  new_cities[i][j].content + '\')"
```

Comment: being that you need to add the single quotes, but to get them you need to escape them (\)

Comment: can you explain a bit more about those "escaping" ? I would really like to understand it..and sure would others too. BTW. answer is correct

Comment: Yeah of course.
"Escaping" as it's called is something you do when you want a characted to be returned or "echo'ed" but it's already used to set a string
So this can be anything between single quotes or double quotes, if, like in your case, you want to actually display a single quote or double quote, you need to tell your code not to parse the following character, by putting a \ (forward slash) in front of it.

Comment: yeah sorry, i pressed enter in between :), i hope my explanation helps you out! Good luck with your project!

Oh one little adendum is that this works in several scripting languages, actually as far as i know it works that way in all web languages..